# Change the speed of subtitles in an srt file

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video, subtitles

I have a set of videos that were recorded at 25 fps. That was the original speed of the video and I want to keep it that way. The video and audio work fine.

I have a corresponding set of subtitle files (srt) that were synced to those videos by someone who had slowed the video to 24 fps before syncing. When you watch the video, the subtitles start off synced up, but over time they get more and more delayed.

How can one programmatically change the timing of the subtitles so that they are sped up by a factor of 25/24? I'm working in a linux environment and I'm looking for a way to change the srt files, not a workaround in my player.

I can delay these subtitles in ffmpeg using the itsoffset option, but delay isn't exactly what is wanted. I can see some tips about speeding up the video or audio, but that's also not wanted.

Thanks in advance for your help.